# What does the ending scene of The Sopranos mean?

Tags: analysis, ending, the-sopranos

In The Sopranos final scene, Tony Soprano was sitting with his family at a restaurant waiting for his daughter to come. And once she did a black screen had appeared and finished the show. So what does that mean? I still don't get it!

Comment: There are many articles about the ending and there is also already a question about the ending here on the website, so I'm voting to close this. Here is the question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/the-sopranos-ending

Comment: @JustMike Hmm. While I agree there are way too many interpretations, the question you linked is about what *happened* in the end (i.e. Plot Explanation) rather than what it *means* (i.e. Analysis). So there might be a *slight* difference.

Comment: @Walt Yes, you are right, but the way this question is phrased it sounds like he's trying to find out what happened. At least that's how I interpreted the question. If I'm wrong and this is a different question, then I think the phrasing should be changed for it to be understandable what is being asked.

Comment: @Walt yeah I'm seeking for the meaning of such an ending

Answer (score 9):

Tony's fate was not made explicit and that was clearly by design. Many theories hold that he was about to be assassinated, but if that was a forgone conclusion, why not depict it?

My personal feeling is that the message is, while Tony may not necessarily die today, his life will always be in some degree of peril because of his career, a wise guy [Sword of Damocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles).

The same goes for his immediate family, Tony Jr. in particular.  Meadow's absence, also clearly by design, is probably an indication that she has the potential to get out of the cycle of crime and violence.

Comment: Exactly  you made it clear.

Comment: ...Though Meadow's potential to move forward is somewhat undercut by her endless struggles with parallel parking. ;)